# Tab bar Event on selected next tab

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, uitabbarcontroller

How to get Event on selected next Tab
Want to load next tab view controller after event trigger.
It create two tab bar for IOS mobile application.

```
public class TabBarController : UITabBarController {
    UIViewController infoController, relatedController,

    public TabBarController ()
    {
        infoController = new UIViewController();
        infoController.Title = "Info";
        infoController.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem ("Info", UIImage.FromFile("/Images/first.png"), 0); 
        infoControllerView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;

        relatedController = new UIViewController();
        relatedController.Title = "Related";
        relatedController.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem ("Related", UIImage.FromFile("/Images/second.png"), 1);
        relatedController.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;

        var tabs = new UIViewController[] {
            infoController, relatedController
        };
        ViewControllers = tabs;}}
```

Second tab will load after a service call result.
based on response data will show result.

Want to know and Event for tab-bar selected tab.

@All

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Add me to skype amir.ios I want to see the code exactly.

Comment: @AmiriDev Thanks for replay..... I need an Event trigger when next tab is clicked. Thats my question.

Comment: you are working in Xcode?